# How to set Datetime in Datatable Datetime column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I'm trying to store currant datetime in Datatable Datetime column using below code

```
dtRow["dCurrantDate"] = DateTime.Now;
```

but getting this error:

> Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store
>   <2019-04-18 12:32:11 PM> in dCurrantDate Column.  Expected type is
>   DateTime.

Comment: Post your errors here in text format, not images.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a method `Now()` - only a property `Now`. Please correct your code. If `DateTime` is a custom object, and not `System.DateTime`, please provide the signature for `Now()`.

Comment: Maybe `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: @Roman Maybe, but given the error, maybe not. Either way, we need a [mcve].

Comment: Please check your column data type

Comment: I also try with System.DateTime.Now but still have same error

Comment: Provide a [mcve], Hardik.

Comment: [Imgur blocked in Turkey](https://www.reddit.com/r/Turkey/comments/8wb85d/why_the_fuck_is_imgur_blocked/). Can you please post your error message as a plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    public void MakeDataTable(){
    DataTable myTable;
    DataRow myNewRow; 
    // Create a new DataTable.
    myTable = new DataTable("My Table");
    //ADDING DATETIME COLUMN
    DataColumn colDateTime = new DataColumn("DateTimeCol");
    colDateTime.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
    myTable.Columns.Add(colDateTime);
    //ADDING ROW TO DATA-Table
    myNewRow = myTable.NewRow();
    myNewRow["DateTimeCol"] = System.DateTime.Now;
    myTable.Rows.Add(myNewRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. My work flow is,  :  ,In Sql Table have dCurrantDate column by shortdatetime datatype. I have created Datatable by fatching Sql Table columns and now i want to store date in Datatable dCurrantDate column from C#. And also have some other column in which i want to store selected date.

Comment: I am getting issue in shortdatetime column attach to datatable column and then store value in Datatable

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in the error message. C# `DateTime` is equivalent to either SQL `datetime` or `datetime2`. Check the type in your SQL table and, if necessary, set it to either of these date types.

If you look at the definition of [smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) here it stores the time differently. If you need the time you will need to strip off all but the hours and minutes, otherwise use the date only. Add `.Date` after `Now`.

Comment: datatype in SQL is shortdatetime. is it possible to convert and store in datatable column?

Comment: Can you change the column type in your SQL table?

Comment: Ohh Sorry but i cant change column type in SQL table

Answer (score 2):

According to the error displayed, the data type of the column in the database does not match the input(if column type is datetime, AM OR PM not stored Use datetime2 Type)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a DateTime column would be added as shown below please cross check with your code 
        `

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

        dc.ColumnName = "dCurrantDate";
        dc.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["dCurrantDate"] =DateTime.Now;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);`
```

Answer (score 0):

double cell = Convert.ToDouble(dataTable.Rows[rowCount][columnCount]);

DateTime matchDate = DateTime.FromOADate(cell);

This is the simplest possible solution.